# Passing URL as a parameter

Tags: apache-flex

```
 <mx:HTTPService id="addWeb" resultFormat="object" result="Added(event)" fault="faultWeb(event)" showBusyCursor="true" method="GET" url="http://localhost/search/populate.php" useProxy="false">
        <mx:request xmlns="">
            <urlWeb>{urlW.text}</urlWeb>
        </mx:request>
    </mx:HTTPService>

 <mx:Text id="query" x="10" y="425" text="Text" width="486" visible="false" height="30" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="16"/>
            <mx:Button x="772" y="424" label="Add" click="addWeb.send();"/>
            <mx:TextInput id="urlW" x="604" y="424" />
            <mx:Label x="513" y="426" text="Add website" />
```

I am passing some random url as parameter, but i am getting this sort of error.

```
[RPC Fault faultString="Error #1096" faultCode="Client.CouldNotDecode" faultDetail="null"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<urlWeb>{urlW.text}</urlWeb>
```

Thats is invalid when Flex parses the request node. You need to use array, object, string, number or xml

```
<mx:String>{urlW.text}</mx:String>
```

Comment: wait I saw your other question.... when are you getting this error?  do you get a result back?

Comment: No i did not get any result back.